# How to filter Array of Functions in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a FUNCTION that returns a random Function from an Array of Functions.

I would like that the returned Function to not be randomly returned twice in a row when the FUNCTION is called again so I use an empty Array to store the last Function returned and then use a filter on the original Array every time the FUNCTION is called to exclude the last function returned.

For some reason the FUNCTION is returning all the functions in the Array instead of one random one.

Also when I checked to see if the filtered Array contained functions it printed 0. So I am very confused.

```
var arrayOfFunctions: [()] = Array<()>()
var lastFunction: [()] = Array<()>()

func myFunction() -> () {
    if !lastFunction.isEmpty {
        let filteredArray: [()] = arrayOfFunctions.filter( { return ($0 != lastFunction)})
        guard let nextFunction = filteredArray.randomElement() else {return arrayOfFunctions[0]}
        lastFunction.removeAll()
        lastFunction.append(nextFunction)
        return nextFunction
    }
    else {
        arrayOfFunctions.append(function1())
        arrayOfFunctions.append(function2())
        guard let nextFunction = arrayOfFunctions.randomElement() else {return arrayOfFunctions[0]}
        lastFunction.append(nextFunction)
        return nextFunction
    }
}
```

Comment: The way to make sure you don't use the same thing in an array twice in a row is to _shuffle_ the array and then _remove_ the first one.

Comment: Indentation = readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `lastFunction` of type `Array<()>()` and then comparing it with a single function `()` element in the below code,

```
let filteredArray: [()] = arrayOfFunctions.filter( { return ($0 != lastFunction)})
```

Instead you must use `()?` as the `lastFunction` type and then do the relevant comparison, i.e.

```
func myFunction() -> () {
    var arr = Array<()>()
    if let value = lastFunction {
        arr = arr.filter { $0 != value }
    } else {
        arrayOfFunctions.append(function1())
        arrayOfFunctions.append(function2())
        arr = arrayOfFunctions
    }
    guard let nextFunction = arr.randomElement() else { return arr[0] }
    lastFunction = nextFunction
    return nextFunction
}
```

Comment: thank you, now my filtered array works as it should but myFunction is still returning both functions in the array instead of only one random function. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the solution by changing the array type to Array<()->()>()